# Ruby - displaying value related to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I am developing a roster planning system by using ruby on rails.

Given that there are three teams in the company. Each team is required to work in shift.

For example,

"1/3/2017" is team A on duty 
"2/3/2017" is team B on duty 
"3/3/2017" is team C on duty 
"4/3/2017" is team A on duty 
etc.,

Here is part of my ruby code.

**seed.rb**

```
roster = Roster.create!(date: "1/03/2017", team: "A")
roster = Roster.create!(date: "2/03/2017", team: "B")
roster = Roster.create!(date: "3/03/2017", team: "C")
roster = Roster.create!(date: "4/03/2017", team: "A")
```

However, I'm wondering how to display which team is on duty on a specific day that isn't stored in seed.rb by calculation.

For example,

How can I make the system display which team is on duty on "11/3/2017" and "15/3/2017" automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Using a gem like ice_cube (https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) might help here. Then you can easily set up recurrence rules and query occurrences.

For example, for three teams `a, b, c`:

```
schedules = {}
start_date = Date.parse('1/3/2017')

%w[ a b c ].each_with_index do |team, index|
  schedules[team] = IceCube::Schedule.new(now = start_date + index) do |s|
    s.add_recurrence_rule(IceCube::Rule.daily(3))  # every 3 days
  end
end
```

You can then query like so:

```
schedules['a'].first(3)
# => [2017-03-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-03-04 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-03-07 00:00:00 +0000]
schedules['b'].first(3)
# => [2017-03-02 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-03-05 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-03-08 00:00:00 +0000]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I am still getting stuck in the problem. How can I set a default date and team in using ice_cube. E.g. (Set 1/3/2017 and team 'A' as the default date and team respectively)   

And how can I display which team is on duty on other date?

Comment: @Jeff: I've updated the answer with a more fully-formed example. Does that help? You'll want to check the documentation on queries like `occurs_on?` and `occurs_between?`